# An error occurred while running cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification

Tags: ionic-framework

While attempting to install the cordova plugins for local-notification for an Ionic Framework cross platform app I received the following:

> Installing "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" for android
>       Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-device@1.1.4" already fetched, using
>       that version.  Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-device" already installed on android.
>       Failed to install 'de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification': Error
>       at
>       /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:205:33

I've already tried the solution at https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications to no avail.  All I'm trying to do is load the plugins as described on Ionic's site:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/ and I they won't install the plugins.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that you have Yarn installed, and that it is clashing with your version of NPM. Try removing Yarn, and your `node_modules` and re-installing.

For example, if you are using Brew, you could do the following:

```sh
# Uninstall Yarn
brew uninstall yarn
brew update
brew doctor

# Uprade Node & NPM  
brew upgrade node
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Then in your project directory:

```sh
cd my-cordova-project
rm -rf node_modules
```

Check your `package.json` for broken links, for example: package dependancies with no version number that linger from installs that did not complete.

```
{
    "name": "helloworld",
    "displayName": "HelloCordova",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",

        // FAILED INSTALL MIGHT CREATE EMPTY VERSION!
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": ""
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": {},
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Now install everything again with `npm`:

```sh
npm install
```

Here is my version info in case that helps you debug:

```sh
node --version
v8.1.4

npm --version
5.3.0

cordova --version
7.0.1
```